# Looping over Array of objects and returning random object value without any duplicate's

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop over array of objects with dynamic length value and expecting random object value without any duplicate's

This is working but it returns duplicated values even the length is within the limit

```
for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
      var item1 =
        test[Math.floor(Math.random() * test.length)];
      console.log(item1);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want it to log just one value? Or `n` values, where `n` is the length of the array? Are you just trying to shuffle (randomly change the order) of the array?

Comment: @ Richard Want to log all values available in the test object without out duplicates eg..If test has 8 obj then log should be 8 number of obj randomly with no dupicates

Answer (score 1):

Store the index you plan on getting and splice it out of the main array.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
      const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * test.length);
      const item1 =
        test.splice(index, 1)[0];
 
      console.log(item1);
}
```

Comment: @ Kitanga, it works but missing to return some test objects, instead returns duplicates eg.test = [{1}{2}{3}]
returns = {1} {4} {1} {3}

Comment: @Rajesh really sorry for taking this long to answer, I'm updating with the correct answer now.